# Can I add Windows 7+ Windows-key shortcuts to Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

One of the computers I routinely work on runs XP and I commonly find myself trying to use shortcuts like

- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>,
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd>,

and nothing happens.  Is there a relatively clean way to add such functionality to XP?

Comment: Some of those shortcuts requires features that only exists in Windows 7.  You can make them do something I suppose, tons of programs that allow you to add shortcuts to Windows on the market, but there is no program that would migrate say Windows 7 only features into Windows XP

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AeroSnap](http://download.cnet.com/AeroSnap/3000-2072_4-10968506.html) for Windows XP/Vista which allows you to use the <kbd>Win</kbd> + Arrow keys shortcut.